# Android Button in Custom Preference gets enabled automatically

Tags: android

I have a custom preference in my application which consists of a 
textview and a button and it is put in a preference screen. I load the 
layout in the onCreateView of the preference

```
LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater)getContext(). 
getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_preference, parent, 
false);
```

In my xml, I have put android:enabled="false" for the button because I 
want to disable it and enable it conditionally later. When my 
preferencescreen comes up, this button is disabled, but gets enabled 
automatically in a second(I still haven't added any code to enable 
this yet). 
Also I find that the onCreateView of my custom preference keeps 
getting called again and again. 
Can someone please help me as to what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your button is disable from xml? I've faced this kind of trouble with textView layout. The `android:enable="false"` wasn't working. Try to disable your button directly in your code on the `onCreate` method like that (assuming your button id in the xml file is `@+id/button`)

`Button myButton;`

`myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);`

`myButton.setEnable(false);`

Then, you'll later be able to enable it with `myButton.setEnable(true);`